# Как присвоить элементу из списка элемент из другого списка?

Tags: python

```
product_urls = []

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    product_data = soup.find_all(
        "div", class_="product_data__gtm-js product_data__pageevents-js ProductCardHorizontal js--ProductCardInListing js--ProductCardInWishlist")

    product_price = soup.find_all(
        "div", class_="ProductPrice ProductPrice_default ProductPrice_size_m ProductCardHorizontal__price")
    product_prices = []

    for prod_data in product_data:
        prod_url = prod_data.find(
            "div", class_="ProductCardHorizontal__header-block").find("a").get("href")
        product_urls.append(prod_url)

    for prod_price in product_price:
        product_prices.append(prod_price.find(
            "span", class_="ProductCardHorizontal__price_current-price js--ProductCardHorizontal__price_current-price").text.strip())

    production_urls = " ----------------    https://www.citilink.ru".join(
        product_urls)

    url_new = "https://www.citilink.ru"

    new_prod_urls = production_urls
    new_product_prices = " ".join(product_prices)
    print(f"{new_prod_urls}{new_product_prices}")
```

на выходе я хочу получить

```
нутбук1 - стоимость
нутбук2 - стоимость
нутбук3 - стоимость
нутбук4 - стоимость
и т.д.
```

заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно, что вам нужно, однако если судить из вопроса и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе, то у вас есть 2 списка, которые можно преобразовать в словарь.

```
b = ['a','b','c','d','e']
a =[1,2,3,4,5]

result = dict(zip(b,a))
print('*',result)

{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

Comment: Этот код не дает требуемые результаты как задумано, потому что переменный product_data и product_price на выходе дают пустой список

Comment: спасибо огромное, все заработало как надо